# SSRS tablix Merging cells vertically problem

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc, rdl

I found the colspan and rowspan property defined in TablixCell,but in report Designer still can't vertical merge cells,if i modify the RDL xml file manually set Rowspan,the reportViewer show me error info:**RowSpan must be 1 for CellContents inside a TablixCell.**

is there any other way to implement vertical merge cells of tablix ?

Comment: Contrary to the prevailing opinion here, you can do this with a tablix, and the process is similar to the one Jonathan posted for the matrix. For the steps to take, see my answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52122160/4879622.

Answer (score 20):

You have to use Matrix instead of Table. I resolved my this problem by creating a matrix same to tablix, below:

1. Insert a Matrix. Right Click->Insert->Matrix
2. Change groupable row to detail row. Right click row->Row Group->Group Properties... Then, in tab "General" Choose "group on" belows "add" and "delete" buttons and click delete to remove group ->OK.

[image]

[image]

3. Right Click at the first column of Matrix and choose "Delete Column" option. Choose radio button (Delete columns only)->OK

[image]

4. Right click on the first row of Matrix and choose "Insert row" option -> outside group - above and then another row will be added to matrix. After that, delete row that you right click previous.

[image]

[image]

5. Now, you can add row above the detail row and can merge any more

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If this is only for display purposes, you could try putting a table inside a table. SSRS will let you do this if you delete the grouping columns on the outside table.

[image: Example SSRS Table in Table]

Otherwise you are limited to the vertical grouping with Matrices, which still has restrictions on where the vertical merging takes place.

Comment: I upvoted this and now can't remove the upvote, but it doesn't work to use this method for layout purposes as you get an error: detail members can only contain static inner members

Comment: @Catherine, when you put a chart or table inside the cell of another table, you need to make sure the "parent" table's row group has a group expression. If the table is selected along the bottom you should see a pane with "Row Groups" and "Column Groups". Double-click on the "(Details...)" group and add a group expression there.

Comment: The nesting tables works very well, except when I set up a subscription to have the report emailed to me. When rendered in outlook, the nested tables do not fill the cell they're in so it looks awful.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the only way to merge vertically, is to use a Matrix instead of a Table.

http://gotreportviewer.com/matrices/index.html

Comment: Hi,Matrix just can use in VS2008 or Vs2005,VS2010 cannot support it,In vs2010 using Tablix replace it,i am talking a about tablix merging cells problem.

Comment: Have used a Matrix with no problem in VS2010 - not sure what you mean here? Had the same issue and confirm you can only merge vertically in a matrix, cannot be done in a table.

Answer (score 5):

So my trick is I highlighted the top row of the column I wanted to merge the cells, and changed the border properties to remove the bottom line.  When you preview the report, the cells look merged.

Comment: That's what I do also, but the text cannot be centered.