# Vertical merge in SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Is there any chance to do vertical merge of fields in tablix?

I am working few years on SSRS, but only saw horizontal merge of cells, vertical not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS tablix Merging cells vertically problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447732/ssrs-tablix-merging-cells-vertically-problem)

Answer (score 11):

Increase the row height to cover what you need. Insert a table to cover the non-merged cells. It's a little tricky to get the alignment right, but it works.

Comment: This is just workaround, but I have appreciate your effort. If I can't find anything else, this will be the option :)

Comment: I have tried it, but now rectangle creates extra td tag and it causes some design issues. can you take a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588372/rectangle-creates-extra-td-tr-tags-in-ssrs-report

Answer (score 8):

***Edit 07/08/2014: Added steps and images.***

If you add a *row group*, it allows vertical merging on the left side of the table. There will be two dotted lines separating the row header and detail. Everything to the left of dotted lines is vertically merged.

If you look at the images from technet there is vertical merging on category and date fields.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220511(v=sql.100).aspx

**Step 1:** Add row group

[image].

**Step 2:** Assign group

[image]

**Step 3:** Voila! You have a vertical merge

[image]

What is your scenario where you need vertical merge?

The other method is what Steven suggested by inserting a table inside a table.

Comment: I know for situation where fields are vertically merged inside group, but I need to merge any two or more fields, whether belong to group or not.

Answer (score 0):

As all know, SSRS provides a simple way to merge cells horizontally.

**Steps for horizontal Merge: Select the cells you want to merge > right click > Merge Cells**

But in SSRS we can't able to merge cells vertically.
To solve this a bit of thinking gets you a work around for this issue.

**To get an effect of merging rows, you can use the same background color and remove the border between common cells.**

**If you have a text to display, Set VerticalAlign cell property to Bottom**
[image]

**And here is the result:**

[image]