# Rectangle Creates Extra td tr Tags in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014, ssrs-2016

I'm using SSRS Report. While using Rectangle in SSRS Report, on web page it creates extra td/tr tags like below image.

[image] Report

*How can I remove such td/tr tags or is there any way to eliminate?*

Actual Image of Design Issue:

[image]

Comment: I have to ask, why do you care? SSRS renders what it gets in the RDL. Is there an extra column in a tablix that isn't really needed? Having more that one tablix on a report that do not align can cause some strange formatting in output.

Comment: I have only one tablix in my report! - In Report Builder it shows perfect design but on web page it doesn't.. :(