# SSRS - 2008: Set Table height till the end of page/ beginning of footer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report-designer

I have a SSRS report, which I need the table to extend till the end of the page. I have 2 tables next to each other and I am using the left table border to serve as a vertical line between them. It is an invoice table and the values are set dynamically.

**The problem:** 
I want to extend the table till the end of the page or better yet set a vertical line till the end of the page, regardless of the values.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Extending the table till the footer, leaving no space in between.
  This works perfectly when I Preview it. But when I save it as PDF the
  this change is not reflected.
- Drawing a line till the footer. This only reflects on first page.
- Setting a line image as background, again this reflects only on first page.

**Ideas:**
To insert blank rows in the table. Compute total number of rows, subtract from a fixed number per page and insert the resultant blank rows.

I have looked mostly everywhere in the MSDN forum, nothing seems to suggest to resolve this issue. Please suggest a solution.

[MyTables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPJkg.png)

Comment: Would something like this from the link work? Adding a group on the right tablix, then drawing the line in the vertically merged row? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880779/vertical-merge-in-ssrs-tablix

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this. This will only extend as long as there is a value in the table. I need the tablix region to extend till the footer even if the table is half full.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rectangle for the area you want to cover (I guess this would be the whole space between your header and footer.

Then add your tables INSIDE the rectangle and add a simple vertical line between them, the full height of the rectangle.

Set the Report property `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` to `True`

Comment: Thank you. This works great. My tables were already in the rectangle. The only problem is when it is rendered to PDF the table does not extend till the end. My report page size is "letter", so while rendering to PDF it tries to fit it to the page.

Comment: Hi @shreyamsh did you find solution?

Comment: Hello @spsaravananct, I had to create 2 different tables. Although not ideal, it works. 
I calculated how many rows can be displayed per page and set the RowGroup Properties Visibility based on the below condition:

`=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing)) > 11 AND (RowNumber(Nothing)) <= 23
      OR ((RowNumber(Nothing)) > 21 AND (RowNumber(Nothing)) <= 30)
       ,False, True
)`