# SSRS - Vertical merge cells in Details rows

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have stored procudure which returns some data like this:

```
Trade mode;Area;Production place;Commodity;Reseller;Min_sell_price;Max_buy_price;Trans_count;Volume;avg_price;change_avg_price;last_trade_price;last_trade_volume
"Trade mode1"; "Area name1"; "Place1"; "Commodity1"; "No";  "33601"; "33601"; "1"; "1200"; "33601"; "+28"; "33601"; "1200"
"Trade mode1"; "Area name1"; "Place1"; "Commodity1"; "Yes"; "-";     "33601"; "0"; "0";    "33601"; "+28"; "33601"; "1200"
"Trade mode1"; "Area name1"; "Place2"; "Commodity2"; "No";  "35000"; "35000"; "1"; "180";  "35000"; "0";   "35000"; "180"
"Trade mode1"; "Area name1"; "Place1"; "Commodity2"; "Yes"; "-";     "35000"; "0"; "0";    "35000"; "0";   "35000"; "180"
```

And I need to create the report is SSRS 2008 R2 which looks like this:

[image: Report example]

I have no idea, how to merge cells in columns "Maximum buyer price", "Average price by commodity", "Average price change", "Last deal price", "Last deal volume". I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would need merged columns in your example. You can increase the height of the cells if you need to fit text onto more than one line.

Also if you use borders carefully you can give the appearance of merged cells even though there are not.

I hope this helps

**EDIT**

I see your example has changed. **Insert a table into the cells you want split vertically**
So price range would be a table inside a table. As would traders.

Comment: How can I synchronize data in inner table with outer table?

Comment: Tables within tables will sort out your issues with setting up the titles at the top of the report but I don't know about the bit with data, where you have '33601' in a merged column. Some people are saying its not possible, but maybe you just need someone smarter than I. Good luck

Answer (score 10):

There is a way to do this, and it is a bit of a hack. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet, so Stack Overflow has linked my images rather than embedding them. Just click the links to see the images. Also, I wanted to include 10 images, but I only have enough reputation to embed 8.
**Edit (Rafalon): I edited this post so we could see the images without having to follow the links every time.**

1. Insert a table.
2. Delete the header row by right-clicking it and selecting "Delete Rows".
3. Right-click a cell in the remaining row, select "Row Group", and click "Delete Group". In the Delete Group dialog box, select the "Delete group only" radio button and click OK.

[image: Delete Group dialog box]

4. The little orange square bracket at the beginning of the row (indicating a group) will disappear.
5. Right-click a cell in the column where you want to vertically merge cells. In this example, the second column. Select "Add Group", then under "Column Group" select "Parent Group...". The Tablix group dialog box will appear. Enter any value in the "Group by" textbox. It doesn't matter what you enter since you will delete it shortly. In this example, I entered "1". Click OK.

[image: Tablix Group dialog box]

Your table will now look like this:

[image: Table with column group]

Notice that there is a new square bracket at the head of the column, indicating there is a group there.

6. Delete the value in the cell (in this example, the "1" I entered).
7. Right-click the cell again and select "Insert Row". Select "Inside Group - Above". Do that again for as many cells as you want to vertically merge (minus 1 for the original cell). In this example, I want to vertically merge 3 cells, so I clicked "Insert Row" > "Inside Group - Above" twice. There are now three rows in the column group.

[image: Multiple rows in the column group]

8. Select all of the cells in the column that you want to merge. In this case, I am merging all 3. You can do this by clicking the first cell, holding shift and click the last cell, or you can hold down Ctrl and click each cell in turn.

[image: Selected cells in column group]

9. Right-click on your selection and click "Merge Cells".

[image: Merged cells]

10. Now right-click on the merged cells, select "Column Group" and click "Delete Group". Again, in the Delete Group dialog box, select the "Delete group only" radio button and click OK. The orange square bracket at the top of the column will disappear.

[image: Column group deleted]

Unfortunately, you will not be able to delete the bottom row that was added when you created the column group.

And there you have it. In the image below, I have a report with 13 subreports. I wanted 2 subreports to show up on the right in the same row as a larger subreport on the left, and it works great.

[image: Example report]

This worked for me in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 11.0.2100.60 (Report Builder 3.0).

I hope this helps.

Comment: If I do it like this, I only get the first row. What goes wrong?

Comment: Are you using Report Builder 3.0? Did you follow all of the steps as I laid them out? As I said initially, the process is a bit of a hack, so who knows what can go wrong. All I know is that it worked for me the way I laid it out.

Comment: Report Builder was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @bryc3m0nk3y you're welcome, your answer helped me and I didn't want to click on every link for each step