# SSRS merge rows vertical in a single column

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer, ssrs-tablix

I'm looking to merge vertical rows for only a single column of my report, so that when that column has lots of data, it doesn't force the left rows to expand.

The answer appears to be using a matrix (e.g. [SSRS tablix Merging cells vertically problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447732/ssrs-tablix-merging-cells-vertically-problem)), but I'm not clear how it would work in this case.

For example, in the screen-shot below, I'd like to spread the confirmation footer text through the following 4 rows, so that the first row (Sales Contact, Angela Thomson, Confirmation Footer, The credit card used...) is the same width as the others and that the Sales Contact info on the left is not pushed down (i.e. the Title row should be just below Sales Contact, and not have all that space in between.

Any thoughts on this?

[image]

Comment: Is there more than one record of data for the report and if there is more than one record how does the report repeat? Is there any data to the right of the confirmation footer?

Comment: There can be multiple records yes, but it is a single-record per page format, with the multiple rows showing data from the single record.  There are no columns to the right of the confirmation footer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a series of nested tablixes. Create each tablix in your report then drag and drop into the main tablix until you get the effect you're after. ([nested data regions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/nested-data-regions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)).

#### Here's the design of 3 nested tablixes

[image: design of 3 nested tablix]

#### Here's the preview of the report

[image: report preview]

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)